# I am using yolov5 with deep sort count coconut which flows in conveyor around 1ms-1 in real time i want to Increase deep sort model processing speed

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, tracking, yolo

**I am using yolov5 with deep sort count coconut which flows in conveyor around 1ms-1 in real time. I used model in following link .**

https://github.com/dongdv95/yolov5/tree/master/Yolov5_DeepSort_Pytorch this GitHub repo.

i have added some parameters and yolo inference speed is 30ms per frame  but deep sort speed 500ms per frame.

follows have my deep sort configuration .I used same model. I didn't do any extra to it.at one time around 40 coconuts coming

```
DEEPSORT:
  MODEL_TYPE: "osnet_x_25"
  MAX_DIST: 0.4 # The matching threshold. Samples with larger distance are considered an invalid match
  MAX_IOU_DISTANCE: 0.2 # Gating threshold. Associations with cost larger than this value are disregarded.
  MAX_AGE: 30 # Maximum number of missed misses before a track is deleted
  N_INIT: 3 # Number of frames that a track remains in initialization phase
  NN_BUDGET: 100 # Maximum size of the appearance descriptors gallery
```

increase speed of tracking. I just want to track small distance after that it will not required. The line.